# Can a database be too relational?

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have a question about database design.  I'm asking here because I'm an enthusiast/hobbyist and not a "professional" so I don't want to post it on the "Database Administrators" stack exchange specifically geared toward professionals.  I hope this is the right place.

I would like to build a system to track encounters between prisoners and corrections officers.  In trying to design a relational database, I've come up with the following five tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `encounters` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `encounterdate` DATETIME NULL,
  `officers_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `prisoners_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `officers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `badgenumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `lastnames_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `firstnames_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `prisoners` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `regnumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `lastnames_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `firstnames_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `firstnames` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `lastnames` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

with the following relationships:
[image: relationship image]

This setup would prevent me from storing all the first names and last names twice (once for the officers and once for the prisoners), but I am not sure how to retrieve a specific officer's first/last name AND a specific prisoner's first/last name for a given encounter.  Ideally, I would like to use a SELECT statement to get a record that looks like one of the rows below:

[image: desired output]

I can use inner joins to get first and last names for either an officer:

```
SELECT
  encounters.encounterdate,
  officers.badgenumber,
  prisoners.regnumber,
  fnames.name,
  lnames.name
FROM
  encounters
  INNER JOIN prisoners ON encounters.prisoners_id = prisoners.id
  INNER JOIN officers ON encounters.officers_id = officers.id
  INNER JOIN fnames on officers.firstnames_id = fnames.id
  INNER JOIN lnames on officers.lastnames_id = lnames.id
WHERE
  officers.badgenumber = "b503"
```

or a prisoner:

```
SELECT
  encounters.encounterdate,
  officers.badgenumber,
  prisoners.regnumber,
  fnames.name,
  lnames.name
FROM
  encounters
  INNER JOIN prisoners ON encounters.prisoners_id = prisoners.id
  INNER JOIN officers ON encounters.officers_id = officers.id
  INNER JOIN fnames on prisoners.firstnames_id = fnames.id
  INNER JOIN lnames on prisoners.lastnames_id = lnames.id
WHERE
  officers.badgenumber = "b503"
```

but I can't figure out if it's possible to get BOTH for a given encounter using only one SELECT statement.

Of course I could do it with a stored procedure/function and a couple SELECTs, but I'm interested to hear if there is a simpler way to do it with one SELECT.  Or is this just a bad way to design a database?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I expect that encounters are sometimes going to involve more than two people. How will you handle an encounter between two guards and a prisoner?

Comment: In reply to Jason, the system is only required to track very specific types encounters that always occur between only one officer and one prisoner.  If/when other individuals get involved, even if it only seconds later, it necessitates another separate encounter record.

Comment: The primary tradeoff you're making is saving space to increase computational complexity. JOINs are not cheap, especially in more complicated and larger databases. Your question has a solution (this design *will* work), but the problem could be easily avoided by not using this table design. I wouldn't use a design like this unless there was a very good reason for it. Just my $0.02, let bygones be bygones, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your example with firstnames and lastnames is interesting. What does it add to the picture? What value does it have to put firstnames in a separate table? If you take all people with firstname "Marc", what do you have then? Does it mean anything? What if you take all people with lastname "Smith" - do they all belong to one family or clan or race or nationality? Do they all live in the same city? Probably not!

If having the name "Smith" meant that you have brown hair, blue eyes and usually dress cowboy style, it would make sense. A possible analogy here is: if the item is a product of type TV, it probably has a remote control, needs a power cable, etc.

If names were like 1MB in size, it would make sense to use an id. That would save a lot of duplicate storage. But with normal names it doesn't make much difference, while it results in more complexity. Not only is the database more complex, but the code connecting to the database is more complex as well, and as there is no benefit you better avoid it.

**As there is nothing meaningful or useful connected to the firstname or lastname, don't put it in a separate table.**

You mention in a comment that it could save 240KB when 20k people have the same name. That's most of the time not a huge save. Of course there are situations where this does make sense, but in the modern world with lots of disk space saving 1MB of data is totally irrelevant.

When you mention the save in data, I wonder if it will cost in performance or not. I have no idea, but if we're talking numbers and this is Facebook and we query millions of names a day, I wonder what will be more efficient, because this means an extra join. This should be tested, and based on that test you decide.

**If you have extreme amounts of queries, or very limited space, and you find that using an extra table saves the day - do it!**

Comment: It saves space and I would presume it makes routine queries faster.  As I mentioned in another comment, frequently querying for distinct names repeatedly (i.e. with jQuery/ajax) might be faster from tables with only unique names. An autocomplete box might refresh/requery after each keypress, so filling it with the results of SELECT DISTINCT from a large table might be less efficient than if the names were stored separately in their own tables. But I'm getting the general idea here that this is probably not best practice... maybe I'll abandon the idea.

Comment: If you find that it makes the Ajax request faster, that is a good reason to do it. If you display large lists of names on a webpage, using an ID might save data download, if you download the names only once and connect it on the page itself using that ID. Still I wonder if it's worth the effort and added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your yes or no question, yes.  Some structures are better off denormalized to an appropriate degree.  What's appropriate?  It depends, of course.
In your particular example, the answer proposed by AEonEX is correct not because of denormalization, but because these names are properly attributes of the entities they name.  It can be appropriate to export a state out of an address because the state is real, has existence, and all references to it actually refer to the same real thing.  A name, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for tables `firstnames` and `lastnames`. Instead store the `firstname` and `lastname` in `officers` and `prisoners` instead of `firstnames_id` and `lastnames_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE `encounters` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `encounterdate` DATETIME NULL,
  `officers_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `prisoners_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `officers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `badgenumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `lastnames` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `firstnames` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `prisoners` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `regnumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `lastnames` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `firstnames` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


SELECT
  encounters.encounterdate,
  officers.badgenumber,
  prisoners.regnumber,
  officers.firstnames,
  officers.lastnames,
  prisoners.firstnames,
  prisoners.lastnames,

FROM
  encounters
  INNER JOIN prisoners ON encounters.prisoners_id = prisoners.id
  INNER JOIN officers ON encounters.officers_id = officers.id
WHERE
  officers.badgenumber = "b503"
```

Comment: Sure, I understand that you can make tables full of the same textual information stored repeatedly for each record, but as I understood it, the ability to avoid this was one of the benefits of a relational database. For example, if 20,000 of the prisoners are named Christopher (i.e. varchar(11)), that requires 12 x 20k = 240 kB whereas just storing integers in each record of the prisoners table that refers to another other table that store "Christopher" once would require about a third of the space, i.e. (4 x 20,001) + 12 = 80,016 B.